# Calculate date from user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I'm trying to create a sort of Date Calculator widget, where dates can be generated based on user inputs to different fields. Thought being if you didn't know the exact date bbut knew it was so many months/years/days ago, you could generate the date using this widget.  In this example, I want to find the date of an event "X" months ago. User inputs number of months ago in field, then a calculation is made to output to the text string saying, the date of the procedure was xx/xx/xxxx.

Here's [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhottle/bVpB2/7/).

html:

Today’s Date:

```
<label for="monthsago" class="col-sm-2 control-label">How many Months ago?</label>
```

Date of Procedure was xx/xx/xxxx.

In all the examples I see here or by googling, it seems the dates are being set in the date object like new Date(2000, 0, 1); I want to use the input fields to generate the date objects calculated. I'm very much a novice at javascript so this is throwing me for a loop. Any input/help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just subtract the month from a date object

```
$('#months').on('input', function () {
    var date  = new Date();
    var month = date.getMonth();

    date.setMonth(month-this.value);

    $('#procedureMonths').text(date.toString());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bVpB2/10/)

Comment: That seems to work great. Now, how do I format the output to just be mm/dd/yyyy? Thanks!